# Laravel 4: How to give immediate feedback after sending email?

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, queue

**This is the situation:**

I have a laravel app that after booking a service it sends an email.
I have installed Iron mq to speed up the process.

Before it was taking 8/10 seconds to send the mail, queueing the email with Iron mq it takes instead around 3 seconds.

Yet i would like to give an **immediate feedback**, that means display a confirmation message instantly.

**This is the controller** (it takes around 3 seconds):

```
        $input = Input::all();

        $validation = Validator::make($input, Registration::$rules, Registration::$messages);

        if($validation->passes()) 
        {

              $registration->name = $input['name'];
              $registration->email = $input['email'];
               ...
              $registration->save();

              $mailer = new Mailers\MailerRegistration();
              $mailer->mailBooking($registration->name, $registration->email)->deliverRegistration();

              return Redirect::back()->with('message','<b>Congratulations! You have succesfully sent the email');
```

**The question is:**

How can i modify the controller in order to give an immediate feedback?
Can i redirect as the first thing first to do, right after checking if validation is passed?
But in this case, what can i pass as RETURN in the end?

I am a little confused..
Hope you can help me!

Comment: Unless you're willing to push the registration process into queue and process them later, then the most straightforward way to do it albeit insecure, is to perform javascript checking and display message to user upon submission then use javascript to call the controller url the ajax way.

Comment: [Laravel Mail Queue](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#queueing-mail). Send using a queue and immediately notify the user that it's been sent.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear enough probably, there is already the Iron mq installed, and already i am queueing the email. But still it takes 3 seconds to do the operation, and i wanted instead to give an immediate feedback. @har2vey you suggest to display a message using js?

Comment: Yep, unless you wanted to push entire registration to iron mq and process them later which would be troublesome, then it's simpler to do validation on js then pass the massage from there before calling the controller from js as well (and you'll still need to do validation on server side).

Comment: Actually i have already a double validation, on client side with javascript and on server side with Laravel. 
Can you please tell me how to make the confirmation message with js? I will consider as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're using the safe way, which is: validate, save model then notify, id go with validate notify then save model if time is critical, but if storing the model fails you need to handle it, you choose your preferred method, you can recreate the model or notify the user or do whatever comes out of creativity to handle the situation.

The reason behind this method, everytime you access the database or the model layer it takes some certain latency, if you notify before then you are pushing the latency to after the notification

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to do something like, putting  Redirect::back()->with('message','<b>Congratulations! You have succesfully sent the email');  right after validation passed. But then i don't know how to close the function, what to pass as RETURN..

Comment: i hope my answer was useful for the previous question, relating to the new question i honestly don't get what you are trying to do here... if you post it as a new question it would be better..